# Select x subitems to new list with LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a HUGE sorted list with integers - Hugelist.

I need to create a new list of items based on input:

Query Hugelist trying to find all series of integers matching my input (variable input like: 5,6,4,9 (ideal dynamic number of inputs).
Numbers has to be in sequence in Hugelist.

Need all matched data (5,6,4,9 AND the next 7 items in Hugelist) added to new list.

So I end up with a list of matches in FilteredList

How on earth do I do this with LINQ and don't foreach my way out of it?

```
hugelist.OrderBy (l => l.Date)
.GroupBy (l => new { l.ID, l.City })
.ToList()
.ForEach(g => g.Aggregate (0, (acc, m)  => { m.DiffToPrev = m.Value - acc; return m.Value; }));
```

DifftoPrev is what I would like to query with multiple inputs (ints).

Comment: and what if `Hugelist` contains `...x,5,6,4,9,5,6,4,9,x,x,x,x,x,x,x...` or what if there is no 7 next values because `5,6,4,9` are last?

Comment: How to query for specific values in sequence and get those plus the next 7 values in sequence in LINQ.

Comment: Need the next 7 items in sequence - no matter their value.

Comment: @MindSwipe, that is not correct about Linq. However, I also agree that this doesn't look like a Linq question.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks @Selvin, didn't know that method existed

Comment: Look like you are trying to solve some SQL problem with Linq. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    List<int> input = new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,6,4,9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    
    List<int> search = new List<int> { 5,6,4,9 };
    
    var test = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count - search.Count)
                         .Where(x => input.Skip(x)
                                          .Take(search.Count)
                                          .SequenceEqual(search)
                               )
                         .Select(x => input.Skip(x)
                                           .Take(search.Count+7)
                                ).SelectMany(x => x);
```

But actually, I would not do it with LINQ but with a loop, because you will iterate quite often over the list and it is not easy readable.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ngzFF

Comment: Thank you. SequenceEqual was what I was looking for. Thank you.